# Setting 2 classNames through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a simple issue, I am trying to have each of this component have two classes. One being `miniplanet` as a default where all components would have, and the other being the props that are passed to it. `{props.className}`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div className=`miniPlanet, ${props.className}`></div>
```

However this is throwing a syntax error, and I can't find anywhere on SOF where someone has the same issue as me. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a single string, so using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) could be a good approach.

Try this:

```
<div className={`miniPlanet ${props.className}`}></div>
```